# Why does THREE.BoundingBoxHelper not display?

Tags: three.js, collada

[image]

I have previously managed to display the box, but here, where I have stripped everything down in order to experiment with expanding boxes by positioning collada models, the box won't show.

```
function loadObjects(){
  cobj = new THREE.Group();
  cobj.name = "5";
  scene.add(cobj);
  pobj = cobj;
  collada("14",pobj);
  collada("7",pobj);
  function collada(key,pobj){
    var nn,file,path,loader,dae,s;
    ns = nset[key].shared;
    model = ns.Product;
    source = ns.Source;
    ext = ns.Extension;
    path = source +model +ext;
    loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.load(path,function (collada) {
      dae = collada.scene;
      dae.name = key;
      sc = 25.4;
      dae.scale.set(sc,sc,sc);
      pobj.add(dae);
    });
  }
  obj = scene.getObjectByName("5");
  console.log(obj);
  helper = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(obj,0xff0000);
  helper.update();
  scene.add(helper);
  sc = 0.1;
  scene.scale.set(sc,sc,sc);
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  $("canvas").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `BoundingBoxHelper` is now `BoxHelper`. It seems you are using a very old release of `three.js`.

Besides, your `collada()` function is not synchronous. After executing `collada("14",pobj);` and `collada("7",pobj);` the assets are not yet loaded which means you are computing the bounding box for an empty group object.

I suggest you wait until the Collada models have been loaded via [THREE.LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager) and then add the helper to your scene.

Alternatively, ensure to call `helper.update()` in your animation loop. This approach is wasteful however if the object is static and does not change. So it's probably better to use the `onLoad()` callback of a loading manager.

Comment: Revived project from when revision 79 was king! But principle the same. TBA interface on right determines relationships; models, groups and BoxHelper set positioning. So your advice spurs me onto to redo with Rev 129 +. Thanks.

Comment: But the download link alerts three.js-master.zip  is invalid

Comment: Try it with: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

Comment: I can download and unzip the file on macOS without issues. Have you tried a different unzip tool?

Comment: Done - overzealous security software